# That's why I(male) like you(female) as a 'sister' Or 'brother'?

Tags: grammar

> That's why I(male) like you(female) as a 'sister' (or 'brother'?)

I'm saying this and I'm male, and who I'm saying to is a girl. So should this be:

> That's why I like you as a 'sister'.

or

> That's why I like you as a 'brother'.

Comment: Why are you saying this. What are you trying to communicate.  As it stands your question is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike some languages ([Korean](http://www.indiana.edu/~korean/E305/kinterms_Korean.html) comes to mind), English does not have different words for relations based on characteristics of the speaker (or other reference individual). A male sibling of yours is a your *brother* and a female sibling is a *sister*, regardless of whether you yourself are male or female, and whether you are older or younger than your sibling. This simplifies things partially.

---

Second, there are different ways *That's why I like you as a sister* can be interpreted, depending on context. It is unclear why you have added quotation marks, which would be used to indicate irony or distancing, but assuming that was not intended, I suspect your question is about the ambiguity between the two most likely interpretations:

> That is the reason why I like you as if you were my sister [as opposed to being just a friend, or as opposed to being a current or potential romantic partner].
>
> Speaking as your sister, that is the reason I like you.

In the absence of other context, the first interpretation is more likely, because it is a common way of delineating what kind of relationship you want to have with another, especially if indicating that you are not interested in other kinds of relationships the other person might be pursuing.

> I like you as a friend[; however, I have no sexual interest in you].
>
> I like you as a co-worker[; however, I would prefer to limit our contact to the workplace, and not spend my free time with you].

The chance of ambiguity is greater when crossing the gender line. If I am female and say *I like you as a brother* to a female or *I like you as a sister* to a male, the friend will need to spend some time trying to interpret the meaning of the words.

---

The word *like* can mean you enjoy someone or something, or that you prefer them to alternatives, or that you are attracted to them. This makes a third consideration tricky to unravel: the social implications of liking someone as a *brother* or a *sister* to someone, something which varies by culture and generation and which is freighted by all the complexities of gender roles and relationships in human societies.

For some possibilities (by no means universal or comprehensive) from the perspective of an American male, consider the following:

- If I say *I like you as a sister* to a female, especially in a speech, it would probably be interpreted as saying *I feel a great deal of affection for you, as a brother would for a sister*. It might be inferred, however, that I am saying *I feel I am the guardian of you and your honor*, which some audiences might take as a slight against their independence. In a personal conversation, it would be  *My affection for you is platonic and I cannot imagine having romantic feelings for you*, which might not be appreciated either.
- If I say *I like you as a brother* to a female, it may be taken as *I respect you the same as a brother*, denying both paternalistic and romantic attitudes in traditional brother-sister relationships. But it is also possible for it to be taken as *I do not value your femininity*, or *I will not restrain my speech or behavior on account of your gender*, which might not be appreciated.
- If I say *I like you as a brother* to a male, it will be taken as a statement that I highly value the friendship, and that I have high regard for and a high degree of intimacy with him. Soldiers, members of sports teams, and of course various "fraternal" organizations use the language of brotherhood to express the solidarity of their members.
- If I say *I like you as a sister* to a male, it will be taken as an insult against his masculinity.

As you can see, this is a delicate matter as it is easy to give offense, especially when addressing a group of mixed backgrounds.

To avoid this minefield, you might avoid the word *like*, and to be especially careful, you might avoid *brother* or *sister*.

> That's why I regard you as part of my family.
>
> That's why I consider you a member of the family.
>
> That's why I feel we are two of a kind.

Answer (score 0):

It could be either one, depending on what you are trying to communicate.

If you simply mean that you like her in the same way you like your siblings, then *sister* would be the obvious choice. But the word *brother* has some connotations that could make it an acceptable option.

Some of the definitions at [Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/brother) include:

- A close friend who accompanies his buddies in their activities
- One who shares a common allegiance or purpose with another or others
- Someone who is a peer, whether male or female

I'd say it really depends on the nature of the relationship. If this girl is a fellow member of a sports team – particularly on a team with a lot more men than women – then *brother* might be a better word to use.

Either option could be risky. Some women might take offense to being called a brother, while others might regard it as a compliment. If you are unsure, you could try:

> *That's why I like you as a brother or sister*.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure why the others are confused.  I assumed that the speaker does not feel romantic attraction to the woman and is expressing that he cares for her as he would care for his sister.  I'm not sure how else you would interpret that sentence.  If my assumption as to your intent is correct, then you definitely want:

> That's why I like you as a sister.

Comment: If I'm a teacher and you are a student then should I say "I like you as a student" Or, "I like you as a teacher"

Comment: @AhsanulIrfan A teacher would say "I like you as a student" to a student.  "I like you as X" means I like you in your role as X.